# Facebook API - Search for mentions of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to search for mentions of my page via the Facebook API?

e.g. get statuses that look like: "I love the page [my page] - have a great day"

Comment: i've tried using the /me/tagged endpoint but it doesnt return mentions

Comment: also thought of using the search API but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Public Post Search is deprecated, there is no way to achieve this, i´m afraid.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if its late for this but I just needed a solution for this. Since `v2.4` you can use the `{pagge-id}/tagged` for this, works really nicely :): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed

Comment: It also finds mentions in a status with `?fields=message_tags`.

Comment: does the post needs to be public in order to get the tagged ?